# Characterisation of symmetric tensors in $V\otimes V$

Tags: tensor-products

Can we prove the following,
if $V$ is a vector space over a field $F$ and $ v\otimes w \ \epsilon\ V\otimes V $ then $ v\otimes w=w\otimes v$ if and only if $v=aw,\  a\epsilon F$.
Preferably without fixing a basis.

Comment: Can you come up with a proof if you allow fixing a basis? I can't think of another way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $v$ and $w$ are linearly independent, there is an $f\in V^{*}$ such that $f(v)=0$ and $f(w)\neq 0$. But then, $f\cdot\operatorname{id}:V\otimes V\to V$ is $0$ on $v\otimes w$ and $f(w)v\neq 0$ on $w\otimes v$, absurd.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's easier to proof the first implication by proving the contrapositive statement, that is, if $v$ and $w$ are two linearly independent linear functionals on $V^{*}$ then $v\otimes w\neq w\otimes v$ (where we are thinking of $V$ as $V^{**}$)

Assuming linear independence, we should have that one of the functionals is not zero, say $v$. Let $\alpha\in V^*$ be such that $v(\alpha)\neq 0$. Since $v$ and $w$ are linearly independent, for every $\lambda\in F$ there's a $\beta\in V^*$ such that $w(\beta)\neq \lambda v(\beta)$. Let $\lambda=\frac{w(\alpha)}{v(\alpha)}$. It follows that $v(\alpha)w(\beta)\neq v(\beta)w(\alpha)$, so, by definition, $(v\otimes w)(\alpha, \beta)\neq (w\otimes v)(\alpha,\beta)$ and therefore, $v\otimes w\neq w\otimes v$.

Comment: $v \in V$ not $V^*$

Comment: I have understood that $V\otimes V$ is the set of multilinear mappings $T:V^*\times V^*\to F$.

Comment: You are identifying $V$ with $V^{**}$, but OK. In that case $\alpha \not\in V$ but $V^*$.

Comment: Thanks, this seems correct but I came across this question in Dummit and Foote in the first chapter on Modules before he discusses Vector spaces in detail so is it possible to have a Module theoretic solution?

Comment: I forgot $V\cong V^{**}$ only true for finite dimensional vector spaces the statement is true in general as shown in the next answer